How can i unlock my gnuplot graph, running from terminal?
When I run the txt script through the terminal, I cannot scale the graph, but if through the GUI application, then everything is fine.
gnuplot -persist PLOT_SCRIPT.txt

How can I change the scale by running the script in this way?
My script:
set grid

unset fit;
x_l = system("more output\\linear.txt");
y_l = system("more +1 output\\linear.txt");

x_n = system("more output\\newton.txt");
y_n = system("more +1 output\\newton.txt"); 

load 'output\\polinom.txt';

set object 1 circle at x_l, y_l size 0.5;
set object 1 circle at x_l, y_l size 0.1 ;

set object 1 circle at x_n, y_n size 0.5;
set object 1 circle at x_n, y_n size 0.1;

plot "data.txt" using 1:2 w l, "data.txt" using 1:2 pt 7 ps 1.5, sin(x) w l lw 4, p(x) w l lw 2

I didn't find set or unset options.

I'm confused. What do you mean by "unlock"? Which gnuplot terminal (or as you probably call it GUI) are you using wxt, qt, png... What do you mean by scaling? Setting the graph (canvas) size or setting the x- and y-range? Please clarify!

by "unlock", I meant that during normal startup, I had a static image that I couldn't move or zoom in/out and wanted me to be able to do
this. fortunately, I just found the answer to my question
set terminal wxt

if you want zoom in/out done picture, you should write
''set terminal wxt''
